# Inserting shifted array back into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So far I have a multidimen array `results`

```
foreach ($votes as $vote) {
            $choices = array();
            Foreach ($vote->getVoteChoicesOrdered() as $choice) {
                array_push($choices, $choice->getAnswer()->getID());
            }
            array_push($results, $choices);
        }
```

Later, I want to remove the first element of each choice in results and shift the positions back up (so I can remove the next element at [0] if I need to)

```
foreach ($results as $res) {
                if (in_array(array_values($res)[0], $losers)) {
                    $shiftedRes = array_shift($res);
                }
            }
```

`$losers` is an array of array keys

Now that I have the shifted array, how would i go about replacing the current `$result` element with the new `$shiftedRes`? Something like `$results[key($res)] = $shiftedRes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of shifting from your $res array, do it directly from the $results array.

```
foreach (array_keys($results) as $key)
{
    if (in_array(array_values($results[$key])[0], $losers))
    {
        $shiftedRes = array_shift($results[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that's a lot nicer - but if I want to update the `$result` for the current key, is it just as simple as `$results[$key] = $shiftedRes`?

Comment: Unless you're adding something else to $shiftedRes it should not be necessary. If the code snippet is from inside a function and $results is passed in as a parameter, either return $result and back to itself or pass it in by reference.

Comment: Otherwise, yes, you can add could manipulate elements in index of the array as you surmised.